# SQL query Excel spreadsheet and combine multiple rows of data into one

Tags: sql, excel

I am working on a project where I have to query a flat Excel spreadsheet and create results like it was a real database.  All of the data is in one worksheet and it looks something like this:

```
Name     City        State   Country     Favorites
John     Austin      TX      US          Hot Dogs
John     Austin      TX      US          Baseball
Steve    Orlando     FL      US          Hot Dogs
Steve    Orlando     FL      US          Baseball
Steve    Orlando     FL      US          Apple Pie
```

With the query I need to return a table that looks like this.

```
Name     City       State    Country     Hot Dogs     Baseball    Apple Pie
John     Austin     TX       US          Yes          Yes         No
Steve    Orlando    FL       US          Yes          Yes         Yes
```

The key is I'm doing this with an Excel Spreadsheet.

So I created a query that looks like this:

```
Select
[Name],[City],[State],[Country],
IIF([Favorites] = "Hot Dogs", 'Yes') as [Hot Dogs],
IIF([Favorites] = "Baseball", 'Yes') as [Baseball],
IIF([Favorites] = "Apple Pie", 'Yes') as [Apple Pie]
From
[Sheet1$]
Group By
[Name],[City],[State],[Country],
IIF([Favorites] = "Hot Dogs", 'Yes'),
IIF([Favorites] = "Apple Pie", 'Yes')
```

However the data results from the query look like this:(apologies for the formatting)

```
Name    City    State   Country    Hot Dogs Baseball    Apple Pie   
John    Austin  TX  US                  Yes 
John    Austin  TX  US     Yes      
Steve   Orlando FL  US                              Yes
Steve   Orlando FL  US              Yes 
Steve   Orlando FL  US     Yes
```

How can I combine all of the results for each user into one row?  Group By doesn't seem to help or work when querying in Excel.  The results are the same whether or not I include the Group By section and I am forced to include all of the columns from the select statement to avoid error:

"You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression...as part of an aggregate function.

If this was in a SQL DB I could make it work, but I'm stuck trying to do this in Excel.

Any suggestions will be created appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: shot in the dark here, but do Union queries work in Excel?

Comment: also if this is from one Excel sheet to another, why resort to SQL at all?  A macro combined with a dynamic range would work wonders.

Comment: Not sure (can't test) but maybe
`Max(IIF([Favorites] = "Hot Dogs", 'Yes')) as [Hot Dogs]` etc might do the job.  Typically columns not in the Group By clause need some kind of aggregation function applied.

Comment: You must definitely use `JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks Brian, Tim, Cha.  Here's what I did and it worked perfectly:

`Select
  [Name],[City],[State],[Country],
  Max(IIF([Favorites] = "Hot Dogs", 'Yes','No')) as [Hot Dogs],
  Max(IIF([Favorites] = "Baseball", 'Yes','No')) as [Baseball],
  Max(IIF([Favorites] = "Apple Pie", 'Yes','No')) as [Apple Pie]
From
  [Sheet1$]   
Group By
  [Name],[City],[State],[Country]`


I really, really appreciate everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

Change the GROUP BY clause, as this:

```
Select
[Name],[City],[State],[Country],
IIF([Favorites] = "Hot Dogs", 'Yes', 'No') as [Hot Dogs],
IIF([Favorites] = "Baseball", 'Yes', 'No') as [Baseball],
IIF([Favorites] = "Apple Pie", 'Yes', 'No') as [Apple Pie]
From
[Sheet1$]
Group By
[Name],[City],[State],[Country]
```

Plus, I think you need to add `, 'No'` in your IIF statements, as I did